# Convert string to date in Angular 8

Tags: angular, date, format, components

In my angular component let's say that i have this string '16/12/2020 12:30:00' (french format).

How can I convert this to an Date object in the component ?

```
expiration_date: Date;
ngOnInit() {

   this.dateService.getOne('EXP_DATE').subscribe((data) => {
      this.expiration_date = new Date(data.value);
   });

    console.log(this.expiration_date);
}
```

I've tried formatDate as well as DatePipe but i get the following message:

> "Unable to convert '16/12/2020 12:30:00' into a date".
>
> undefined

Comment: please try this.    `new Date(Number(Date.parse(data.value)))`

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
expiration_date: Date;
ngOnInit() {

   this.dateService.getOne('EXP_DATE').subscribe((data) => {
      this.expiration_date = Date.parse(data.value);
      console.log(this.expiration_date);
   });
}
```

Edit:
The reason likely lies within your date format`

> Note: Parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and
>   Date.parse(), which works the same way) is strongly discouraged due to
>   browser differences and inconsistencies. Support for RFC 2822 format
>   strings is by convention only. Support for ISO 8601 formats differs in
>   that date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, not
>   local.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: I had tried this already as well, but Date.parse() return a number, which is not a Date;

And new Date(Date.parse(data.value)) doesn't work either

I'm just super bad when it comes to dates manipulation :<

Answer (score 1):

I think first you have to **split** your date string to convert it into Date object, something like below (you can put below logic into separate function to handle date manupulation)

```
let dateString='16/12/2020 12:30:00';

let date=dateString.split(' ');

const dateObj=new Date(date[0].split('/')[0],date[0].split('/')[1],date[0].split('/')[2],date[1].split('/')[0],date[1].split('/')[1],date[1].split('/')[2]);

console.log('dateObj::',dateObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

install `date-fns` and using `parse` function:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { parse } from 'date-fns';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  date: Date = null;
  ngOnInit() {
    const data = {
      value: '16/12/2020 12:30:00'
    }
    this.date = parse(data.value, 'd/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss', new Date());
  }
}
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nlsuny